# express router.get() function SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a route to return JSON data from a JSON-RPC API.

My code:

```
router.get('/balance', function(req, res, client) {
    res.json({
        client.getBalance('*', 1, function(err, balance) {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log('Balance: ', balance);
        });
    });
});
```

It's using the npm package node-litecoin.  I have required it and created a client var like so:

```
var client = new litecoin.Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9332,
    user: 'myaccount',
    password: 'mypass'
});
```

client.getBalance('*', 1, function(err, balance) {
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: How can I have the route `'/balance'` output the client.getBalance() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I getting this error?

Because `client.getBalance('*', 1, function(err, balance) {` cannot be there where you put it.

Lets have a closer look:

```
res.json({ ... });
```

The `{...}` here indicate an [**object literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers). The "content" of the literal has to be a comma separated list of `key: value` pairs, e.g.

```
res.json({foo: 'bar'});
```

You instead put a function call there:

```
res.json({ client.getBalance(...) });
```

which simply is invalid.

---

> How can I have the route `'/balance'` output the `client.getBalance()` function?

It looks like `client.getBalance` is an asynchronous function call, hence passing its return value to `res.json` wouldn't work either. You have to pass the result that you get in the callback to `res.json`:

```
router.get('/balance', function(req, res) {
    client.getBalance('*', 1, function(err, balance) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log('Balance: ', balance);

        res.json(balance);
    });
});
```

If you are not very familiar with JavaScript's syntax, I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: Well, that simply means that `client` doesn't have a method `getBalance`. Since I don't know what `client` is supposed to be or what `getBalance`  is supposed to do, there is nothing I can do to help you here.

Comment: Oh, you where initializing `client` as a variable somewhere. Then I guess simply removing `client` from parameter list fixed it.

Comment: Right.  Stupid mistake.  Thanks.